# ONLY redirect certain path with dnsmasq and nginx

Tags: nginx, dnsmasq

I am trying to redirect ONLY one path using dnsmasq and nginx.

For example, in `dnsmasq.conf` I have the following

```
address=/foo.com/127.0.0.1
```

For this example let's assume the app/client is making requests to `foo.com/1`, `foo.com/2` and `foo.com/3`

What I am trying to accomplish is to ONLY redirect `foo.com/3` to my localhost node server that is running. For `foo.com/1` , `foo.com/2` or `foo.com/*` I want it to go out into the internet and resolve like it would anything else.

I would assume I could accomplish this in nginx. I'm just not sure how. I figure it would be something along the lines of `return $oringalURL`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!